# Derivative of log determinant of matrix-valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

It's a standard result from matrix calculus that for $X \in \mathbb{R}^{b \,\times\, c}$, we have
$$
    \frac{\partial \ln\det(X^t X)}{\partial X} = 2(X^\dagger)^t,
$$

where $X^t$ denotes matrix transpose, and $X^\dagger$ the pseudoinverse.

I'm currently faced with the following problem, and I don't have enough knowledge of matrix calculus to know how to proceed. Let $f_\theta : \mathbb{R}^a \to \mathbb{R}^{b \,\times\, c}$ be parameterized by a vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^a$. I would like to compute
$$
    \frac{\partial \ln\det(f_\theta(x)^t \, f_\theta(x))}{\partial \theta}. 
$$

From the identity above, I'm guessing that the result will take the form
$$
    2 (f_\theta(x)^\dagger)^t \;\square\; (D_\theta f_\theta)(x),
$$
where $D_\theta$ denotes differentiation with respect to $\theta$. But I don't know what $\square$ should be, since the first term is a $b \times c$ matrix, and the second term a $b \times c \times n$ tensor.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In this case, the symbol $\square$ stands for the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product, which is usually denoted by a colon (which is much easier to type).$$ $$In index notation, given two tensors, $A=A_{ijk}$ and $B=B_{jkmp}$, their Frobenius product is $$\eqalign{C &= A:B\cr C_{imp} &= A_{ijk}B_{jkmp} }$$

Comment: @greg Thanks for your response! In my case, if we let $A := 2(f_\theta(x)^\dagger)^t$ (of size $b \times c$) and $B := (D_\theta f_\theta)(x)$ (of size $b \times c \times n$), I'm guessing that the result is given by $C_k = \sum_{ij} A_{ij} B_{ijk}$?